# Firefox plays no M4A audio file from the internet, localhost is working

Tags: javascript, firefox, audio, m4a

I have a strange problem and already lost several hours on it:

When I try to play any M4A audio file from a web location in Firefox I get an error message that the video format or mime type is not supported.
But when I download the same M4A file an play it locally from disk in Firefox it is working.

I tried it with this file: 
http://techslides.com/demos/samples/sample.m4a

In Chrome and IE everything works.
I use Firefox 53, 32-bit version.

Has anyone an idea how I can solve this in Firefox?

**UPDATE:**

I set up a test page to clarify the differences in Firefox:

http://123-bb.de/tests/audiotest

The result is interesting: The first M4A file is played without problems if called from a link directly, but doesn't play when called as Javascript Audio.
The second file is the opposite.

So the question is, how can I get Firefox to set the mime type correctly when loaded as a Javascript Audio Element?

Answer (score 3):

The issue with Firefox and m4a format is due to licensing. Browser is using built-in OS libraries to play the file to not pay the license fee. The m4a file to be played [needs to be in mp4 container](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/html5-audio-and-video-firefox#w_patented-media_2) - it needs to have `audio/mp4` [MIME type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types).

The file you have linked when played from the link has  - `audio/mpeg`. When I tried embeding it [in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oegaze81/) firefox detect it correctly as - `audio/mp4` due to server configuration.  You can control the MIME type of a file but only on your server, more on that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Configuring_server_MIME_types#How_to_set_up_your_server_to_send_the_correct_MIME_types).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I set up a test at http://123-bb.de/tests/audiotest and it seems that firefox detects the mime type for the same file differently. The sample file above is played well if called from Javascript as an audio element. Another file with correct mime type is the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer to my question from the Firefox team:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1362358

In short: There are 2 different ways how Firefox looks up the mime type. When the audio file is called from a Javascript audio object, Firefox ignores the mime type from the http response and detects it by sniffing into the audio file.
My M4A files have a 3gpp encoding and this codec is not supported by Firefox.